# how to change the permisson of system/xbin/su

Tags: android

I compiled `su` to `system/xbin` but its permissions are `-rwsr-x---`.  How to change it to `-rwsr-x--x`?  I have tried to use the commands below in `init.rc`, but they make no difference.

on boot 
...

```
chown root system /system/xbin/su
chmod 5751 /system/xbin/su
```

Comment: chmod 4751 /system/xbin/su did not make a difference

Comment: Have you tried 777 (3 digits)?